# Converting multiple types of values to integer values

Tags: pandas, csv, integer

I have a Pandas DF in which I want to convert column values to integer values. The information should be stored in meters but can be stored in kilometers as well, resulting in the following possible values:

```
23145 (correct)
23145.0 (.0 should be removed)
101.1 (should be multiplied *1000)
47,587 (should be multiplied *1000)
'No value known'
```

I tried different options with converting data types, but I always seem to break the existing integers and cannot check for them correctly because the type 'object' is the dtype. Sometimes faulty values or strings block conversion as well.

Any ideas how to check if the value currently is an integer and do nothing, remove .0 from applicable values and multiply where applicable.

I also have some other columns with integers (e.g. number 22321323) where randomly a .0 is assigned (e.g. number 22321323.0). How can I correctly convert these values to not include the .0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a .apply on the column, you should be able to very easily convert these values while casing on their type. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
def convert(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, float):
        return int(x)
    else:
        # Defaults to 0 when not convertable
        return 0
    print(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [23145, 23145.0, 'No value known']})
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(convert)
```